# Extjs 3 to Extjs 4

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs3

I want to migrate from extjs 3 to extjs 4. I have tested [sample](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/guide/application_architecture) Extjs 4 example in rails 3. I have observed that page rendering time is very slow in extjs 4. I don't know what is the reason.
Can anybody tell me, what is the reason behind that? or
is there any problem in my app? and
What should I do to improve the perfomance of extjs 4?

Comment: had u observed if it's an ajax problem(network) or ext render problem?

Comment: Thanks for reply, But I have tested on local host. I think its not any ajax problem. And also had comapare the same application with ext 3. I don't use any grid. I am just showing a simple form still its slow. I don't know why it is so.

Comment: I'm using grails1.4M1+extjs4.0.2, but don't see it's slow.maybe u had to put up more info

Comment: @atian25. so it is possible that my rails application can be the reason. But my application performs well with extjs3.

Comment: The best thing you can do is to create a simple reduction that shows the problem, then people can analyze it. It's hard to help when you just say "My Ext-4 app is slow"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ExtJS 4.0 has performance issues,

ExtJS 4.0.2 is the release you need that fixes most performance issues, it is still slow though...

Google for ExtJS 4 performance

Comment: Downvote for comparing ExtJS to jQuery.

Comment: @dmackerman, I'm comparing the quality and performance, not the features of those frameworks. Have you used ExtJS, Dojo and jQuery?

Comment: @Dzhu: Ext-JS and jQuery are completely different beasts, don't compare oranges and apples. jQuery is like Ext-Core http://www.sencha.com/products/extcore/, try measuring performance on those two. Ext-JS is more like jQueryUI (but jQueryUI is not nearly as nice). Dojo is a better comparison. jQuery is for progressive enhancement and Ext-JS is for web applications that require JS. I'm using Ext-JS 4.0.6 and though I do think Ext-JS 4.0 was not thoroughly tested (found way too many bugs myself), I still think it's the most complete UI framework/library for the web.

Comment: @JuanMendes I've used dojo and extjs extensively in many commercial projects (Ajax JEE applications). ExtJS is very restrictive in how you can do things using it. One of the worst things about ExtJS is the way it lays out components - if you do not give components explicit width / height declarations, this sometimes causes 'too much recursion' exceptions. Secondly, everything needs to be defined in javascript, it makes the code very hard to read, with dojo, you can extern html in template files. ExtJS being the 'most complete' framework? I highly doubt that, you could only call it a framework

Comment: @Dzhu: There is a steep curve to learning it. But as advanced user, Ext's component architecture allows me write clean OO UI that is testable, reusable and decoupled. Your problems with layout seem to be from a misunderstanding of the layout pipeline. In an Ext-JS application, that is handled by layout managers, you just specify how you want them laid out. Mixing CSS layout and certain Ext-JS widgets requires that you set their width, never seen problem with heights.

Comment: Also, I think laying out designing user interfaces with HTML is not very friendly. HTML was intended for laying out documents, not applications. XUL is better but I really prefer using JSON. To each his own.

Comment: @JuanMendes There is no doubt that a framework like ExtJS offers a way to write maintainable code. I havn't written any tests for extjs code, care to share how some examples? Layout - css is more universally understood. the layout mechanism in extjs also causes most of its performance issues. The problem with height is manifested in tabs and panels in that tab. We just ran into it a few months ago...

Comment: @JuanMendes about designing ui with HTML - in the end, everything is converted into dom/html/css, there is no magic about it. What bothers me is ExtJS forces you to declare all layouts etc in javascript - Have a look at how dojo separates templates from javascript code.

Comment: @JuanMendes: What is the reason I was downvoted? speak up

Comment: @Dzhu: Wasn't me, I agreed with some of your concerns on Ext-JS, I only disagree that Dojo is easier to use :)

Comment: Downvote for comparing ExtJS to jQuery (2)

Answer (score 4):

Did you forget to turn off dynamic resource loading? Note that ext*-all.js will speed up your page loading dramatically.

Answer (score 3):

ExtJS 4 is much faster than ExtJS 3. Guys from sencha solved a lot of rendering problems and improved performance greatly.

In the sample link just read the deployment section. The performance there is normal issue for development as in 4th version was introduced ext loader and it is much better for debugging and development using concrete short files of the framework instead of loading big files (more than 100k lines) and you always knows where the problems are.

In production you need to use Sencha SDK which will generate yours application initial required js plus extjs dependencies. It is much better than it was in 3rd version where you need to load all the framework.

Answer (score 3):

You can run Sencha CMD, a ruby gem which dynamically creates your ExtJS 4 css file, allowing you to cut the full css file (~ 500kb !) down to something less ridiculous.

I have outlined this process in April here https://docs.google.com/document/d/1lGfbEoktJNhIpZneeJ2kkjNKOaSYpOse3mnSA5mGEds/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

Extjs 4.1 is resolved many issues related to the layouts. If you have nested panels, does better rendering when compared to the Ext 3.

Comment: By "better rendering" are you referring to speed/performance, which is what the OP Was asking about?

Comment: Performance.  In particular saw huge difference in the performance with border layout.

Answer (score 2):

1. It may seems to be late reply, but the truth is ExtJS 4.x is much fast than ExtJS 3.x version, more over it made front-end developer to create their application with a MVC pattern approach to organize their coding structure much more clearer an maintainable.
2. ExtJS 4.x solve rendering problems an improved in performance over browser compatibility also.
3. To answer your question, it may be many reason as stated below.

   1. Check with the developer tool, which part of js file taking more time to load as compare to extjs 3.x
   2. you may be using more inner components(adding more items to parents and child component having more sub-components,etc).
   3. Even you can use the newly-introduced Sencha SDK Tools (download here) makes deployment of any Ext JS 4 application easier than ever. The tools allow you to generate a manifest of all JavaScript dependencies in the form of a JSB3 (JSBuilder file format) file, and create a custom build containing only the code that your application needs.

Note: Its all depends on, how you design your application (Architect).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

ExtJS 4.x is contain lot of bugs in comparison  ExtJS 3.x. I am using both in my different project.  for example 4.0.7 contain file upload issue till now so i want to tells my opinion 
extjs 3.x is more stable release of extjs frame work.

Answer (score 0):

Use MVC feature of Extjs4.0 or later version 
put store views model controller in different folder
and call them using controller.